# Is there a way to send a POST request for Google Calendar API without using the library? Java

Tags: android, calendar, google-api, google-play-services, http-post

I'm using the Google Play Services library to log in with Google Plus. With this library I can retrieve the access token to send requests to the Google Services like Calendar.

I already got a GET request for events, but I'm having problems with a POST request. Here's the GET request:

HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

```
    String resultJSON = null;

    ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();

    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(baseurl + params[0]);

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "
                + ProjectModel.getInstance().getOauthToken());

        resultJSON = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(
                urlConnection.getInputStream(), Charsets.UTF_8));

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(resultJSON)) {
            JSONArray resultArray;

            resultArray = new JSONObject(resultJSON).getJSONArray("items");
```

The URL for POST is the same as this request:

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/id/events

Problem is, I can't find a way to convert this into a POST request. Anyone knows a way to get this done WITHOUT using the Calendar Libraries?

Thanks!

Comment: how about a picasa api think you can make it work with your calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a post request with httpURLConnection for picasa backdoor simulating the gdata library.  It should be similar to what your doing.  I know your sending JSON so you'll have to work that piece out substitute your json for the xmlString and change the content type.

```
    private Document createAlbum() throws ParseException, IOException,
            ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {

        String xmlString = "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'"
                + " xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'"
                + " xmlns:gphoto='http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007'>"
                + "<title type='text'>"
                + GoPreferences.getString(context,
                        SettingRecord.ALBUM_NAME,
                        SettingRecord.ALBUM_NAME_DEFAULT)
                + "</title>"
                + "<summary type='text'>"
                + "This was the recent trip I made"
                + "</summary>"
                + "<gphoto:location></gphoto:location>"
                + "<gphoto:access>public</gphoto:access>"
                + "<gphoto:timestamp>"
                + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())
                + "</gphoto:timestamp>"
                + "<media:group>"
                + "<media:keywords></media:keywords>"
                + "</media:group>"
                + "<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'"
                + " term='http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#album'></category>"
                + "</entry>";

        URL url = new URL(
                "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default");
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        // clientid may not be necessary
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("X-GData-Client", CLIENT_ID);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("GData-Version", "2");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth "
                + token);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/atom+xml");

        OutputStream stream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

        OutputStreamWriter sw = new OutputStreamWriter(stream, "UTF-8");

        sw.write(xmlString);
        sw.flush();
        sw.close();
        stream.close();

        if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() != 201) {
            return null;
        }

        InputStream result = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(result);

        String href = "";
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("link");
        int i = nodeList.getLength();
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(j);
            NamedNodeMap attr = node.getAttributes();
            if (attr.getNamedItem("rel").getTextContent().equals("edit")) {
                href = attr.getNamedItem("href").getTextContent();
                break;
            }
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(href)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            GoPreferences.putString(context, ALBUM_URL, href);
            return doc;
        }
}
```